# Does the browserslist option in Gulp's Autoprefixer plugin define what browsers should be included or excluded?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-autoprefixer

Possibly the dumbest question I've asked but I'm finding the documentation and the limited examples quite hazy.

I'd like to support as many browsers as possible, including IE7+ e.g.

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 5 versions', 'ie >= 7']
})
```

Logically, I assume the 'browsers' option above exists to define exactly which browsers, or range of browsers, should be supported. In other words, the above may translate as:

"Support the last 5 versions of every browser AND ensure that all versions of IE (from 7 upwards) are supported."

Another way of saying it:

"Don't remove any styles that are required by these browsers"

Have I understood the `browsers` option correctly please?

Comment: By the way, Autoprefixer team recommends few changes:
1. Use `browserslist` config file or `browserslist` option in `package.json`. In this case many other tool will use this browsers.
2. `gulp-autoprefixer` is not official way. Official way is `gulp-postcss` with `autoprefixer`, because you will receive updates faster.

Comment: Ah, so with regard to postCSS, something like this?: `.pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ remove: false, browsers: ['last 5 versions', 'ie >= 7'] }) ]))`

Comment: The best way: `.pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ remove: false }) ]))` in `gulpfile.js` and `"browserslist": ["last 5 versions", "ie >= 7"]` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap, you understand `browsers` correctly. `['last 5 versions', 'ie >= 7']` means “Support the last 5 versions of every browser *and* ensure that all versions of IE (from 7 upwards) are supported”.